# Invisible \u00A0 character before is_object() authorize.net

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am using the [sample code](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/PaymentTransactions/charge-credit-card.php) from the PHP SDK and the package throws an error of

> Call to undefined function net\authorize\api\contract\v1\ is_object().

It looks like its coming from this call:

```
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
```

That in turns calls this:

```
vendor/authorizenet/authorizenet/lib/net/authorize/api/contract/v1/CreateTransactionResponse.php:72
```

I saw an issue open on their Github page that's been around for a bit now. Anyone else seen this? How can you fix this if its coming from the actual vendors code?

Comment: Until they fix it either fork it and make a fix and use your fork of the repository or use an alternative library.

Answer (score 0):

Using their API directly, not through the SDK, the response had three invisible characters at the start. Since it is a JSON response, I created a loop that would remove the starting character until a opening bracket is encountered. You may be able to fix their SDK with something similar.

```
    while ('{' !== $cleaned_response[0]) {
        $cleaned_response = substr($cleaned_response, 1);
    }
```